# Refresh browser cache memory with javascript

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

Is there any js function that refreshes browser cache? 
i.e deleting a row in a table and seeing the result on the browser straight away without the need of logging off and logging in to the system to see the change?

Comment: There is a way. It's not a function. It's something else entirely. Your question is too vague. Why would you need to log off and log on? What's wrong with reloading the current URL?

Answer (score 2):

```
location.reload(true);
```

Forces (in most browsers) the page to be reloaded from the server, and *not* loaded from a cache.

The argument given to `reload` specifies whether or not it should force fetching new data over loading from the cache.